# Gassing a lager keg

Tags: beer

I have 2 bars, both with lager kegs. One is gassed with co2 and the other is with mixed 60/40. Can I use a half used keg from one bar in the other, ie mixing the gasses in the keg or do I need to de gas it?

Comment: What is a lager keg? Do you mean a keg filled with lager, I.E. beer? And what gases are in the 60/40 mixture of gas you have in one keg?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that although you may encounter some problems.  The beer gas (60/40) is likely at a higher pressure, so hooking a conventionally carbonated keg may (repeat, MAY) cause it to dispense with too much pressure and cause excessive foaming.  That might require reducing the serving pressure by adjusting the beer gas regulator.  OTOH, it may not be a problem.  I say try it and adjust accordingly if you have to.

Comment: I thought beer gas was more 80/20? (N2/C02) Or am I thinking of strictly what we in the states would call a 'nitro gas' blend?

Comment: Nitro pressure is a lot higher than CO2. But I am not sure how much. I would just depressurize the keg and then connect it. That way you can't be wrong.

Comment: @brewchez, you get 100 (pure CO2), 80 (80% CO2, 20% Nitro) 60 (60% CO2, 40 % Nitro). I do not know it goes any further. (These numbers are in South Africa, USA may be different.)

Comment: All the "beer gas" I'm familiar with in the US is 60/40.